# Log-Manager:Write-Message

Tags: progress-4gl

I am using log-manager for creating some logs with below setting:

```
log-manager:LOG-ENTRY-TYPES   = ""4GLMessages:2""
```

The log gets created with the messages I have in `LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE` plus  progress stack and view-as alert messages which I don't want. I want only the messages I write through `LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE`. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

The 4GLMessages entry type is reserved for the MESSAGE Statement. If you don't want those to be written to the log file, don't use the 4GLMessages log entry type.

From the online help:

4GLMessages:

Turns on logging of ABL messages. OpenEdge writes all ABL VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX messages to the log file, together with the ABL stack, when you turn on Debug Alert using either the Debug Alert (-debugalert) startup parameter or the DEBUG-ALERT attribute on the SESSION system handle.

The LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE Messages are written in any case!

Or are you trying to avoid runtime error messages to show up in the logfile?